# SQL duplicated visitors per product

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Main table and visitors and I link them up by Date and Hour( I have only Date, hour and Visitors in Visitors table)

This is my table

```
DATE        HOUR  ORDER_ID   ITEM     VISITORS
2018-09-25  14    123456     Box      140
2018-09-25  14    345677     Paper    140
2018-09-25  14    234678     Bear     140
```

BUT I need somehow to make it like this, to remove duplicated visitors, is it possible at all?

```
DATE        HOUR  ORDER_ID   ITEM     VISITORS
2018-09-25  14    123456     Box      140
2018-09-25  14    345677     Paper    
2018-09-25  14    234678     Bear
```

I'm looking for logic to understand how to do it. **As I need Visitors in the same table**

Comment: MySQL or Google-bigquery.. You should not be tagging two different RDBMS systems.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I need big query, but if it will be done in any other SQL syntax I will adapt it, I just cannot understand the logic of how to do it.

Comment: "I need big query, but is it will be done in any other SQL syntax I will adapt it" Not logical most likely Google-bigquery has other extended SQL implementation on top of the standard ANSI SQL standards MySQL has.. In MySQL this is possible with user variables which Google bigquery does not have.

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry then, I need it In BigQuery (Standard SQL) not the Legacy one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select date, hour, order_id, item,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by date, hour order by order_id) = 1
             then visitors
        end) as visitors
from t;
```

This will include `visitors` on only one row for a given date and hour.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like what you really need looks like below

```
DATE        HOUR  ORDERS.ORDER_ID    ORDERS.ITEM      VISITORS
2018-09-25  14    123456             Box              140
                  345677             Paper    
                  234678             Bear
```

to get to this you can use something like below (with some assumption about your tables based on limited info)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.main_table` AS (
  SELECT '2018-09-25' DATE, 14 HOUR, 123456 ORDER_ID, 'Box' ITEM UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-09-25', 14, 345677, 'Paper' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-09-25', 14, 234678, 'Bear' 
), `project.dataset.visitors_table` AS (
  SELECT '2018-09-25' DATE, 14 HOUR, 140 VISITORS 
)
SELECT DATE, HOUR, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ORDER_ID, ITEM)) ORDERS, SUM(VISITORS) VISITORS 
FROM `project.dataset.main_table` m
JOIN `project.dataset.visitors_table` v
USING(DATE, HOUR)
GROUP BY DATE, HOUR
```